# Wget or bash alters a timestamp value with an extra interposed space

Tags: bash, wget

At the bash prompt we have:

```
bash> if_modified_since=`date --date="2 hours ago 5 minutes ago" +%a,\ %e\ %b\ %Y\ %H:%M:%S\ GMT`
bash> echo $ts_modified_since
Mon, 3 Aug 2015 08:45:18 GMT
```

Notice how there is a single space between `Mon,` and the trailing `3 Aug...` which is as expected.

But when trying to use the value `$if_modified_since`, there is an extra space inserted after `Mon,` with the sent headers:

```
bash> wget -S -d --header="If-Modified-Since: $if_modified_since" http://...

<snipped connection handshake>
---request begin---
GET ...
User-Agent: Wget/1.16.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: xxx.xxxxx.xxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
If-Modified-Since: Mon,  3 Aug 2015 08:45:18 GMT

---request end---
<snipped rest of response>
```

The timestamp is apparently sent as:

```
Mon,  3 Aug 2015 08:45:18 GMT
```

The extra space renders the `If-Modified-Since` header incomprehensible by the receiving server, and is thus ignored.

Was initially inclined to think `wget` was the cause, but hard-coding the value `Mon, 3 Aug 2015 08:45:18 GMT` works as expected:

```
<snipped connection handshake>
---request begin---
GET ...
User-Agent: Wget/1.16.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: xxx.xxxxx.xxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 3 Aug 2015 08:45:18 GMT

---request end---
<snipped rest of response>
```

I suspected the comma after `Mon` to being treated in a special manner, but escaping or even removing it led to same results. I am also aware of [Bash's brace expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003553/1787400), but this is not the case here.

**Workaround 1**: use `/bin/date` formatting with 2-digits for day of month (`%d` instead of `%e`):

```
bash> if_modified_since=`date --date="2 hours ago 5 minutes ago" +%a,\ %d\ %b\ %Y\ %H:%M:%S\ GMT`
bash> echo $ts_modified_since
Mon, 03 Aug 2015 09:13:30 GMT
```

**Workaround 2**: let `/bin/date` format the timestamp according to the RCF 2822 which results in same formatting:

```
bash> if_modified_since_ts=`date --utc -R --date='5 minutes ago'`
bash> echo $ts_modified_since
Mon, 03 Aug 2015 09:13:30 GMT
```

Both workarounds resolve the issue:

```
bash> wget -S -d --header="If-Modified-Since: $if_modified_since" http://...

---request begin---
GET ....
User-Agent: Wget/1.16.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: xxx.xxxxxx.xxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 09:13:30 GMT

---request end---
```

Still, regardless of the workarounds, why is this happening in the first place? I'm on bash version 4.3.30(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a simple quoting issue. Viz.:

```
$ if_modified_since=`date --date="2 hours ago 5 minutes ago" +%a,\ %e\ %b\ %Y\ %H:%M:%S\ GMT`
$ echo $if_modified_since     # Shell performs word-splitting, echo sees 6 args
Mon, 3 Aug 2015 11:07:34 GMT
$ echo "$if_modified_since"   # Shell does not perform word-splitting, echo sees 1 arg
Mon,  3 Aug 2015 11:07:34 GMT
```

There is also no "extra space", since the `%e` specifier is documented as using a leading space for one digit numbers. From `man strftime`:

```
        %e     Like %d, the day of the month as a decimal number, but  a  leading  zero  is
               replaced by a space. (SU)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second line:

```
bash> echo $if_modified_since
```

Is fusing the internal spaces to only one. Try quoting:

```
bash> echo "$if_modified_since"
```

I like to use `date --date="2 hours ago 5 minutes ago" +%s`, it never repeats, its immune to a change of timezone or DST, and has no spaces, reducing possible wrong interpretations by software.

Of course, the 822 format is a common time interchange format (better if UTC).

However, why not use the automatic timestamp checking of wget?

You could check the timestamp of the file, or even change it, and wget will check if the header timestamp is newer than the file timestamp. Just use `-N` for wget.

note: file timestamp is read as this: `date -Rr $filename`

R for rfc-822 style, r for reference (file). Many other formats are possible.

Comment: The -N is not an option because we are not maintaining the downloaded files for comparison. I just need to get through a cron job that runs every 5 mins, the new files that might have been added to a web directory.