# bash here document syntax I want to ignore newlines

Tags: bash

I would like to use the bash here doc syntax to build a long string. I would like the heredoc to ignore newlines/spaces/tabs even when I use newlines for code clarity.

I thought this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

#http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/how-to-add-newlines-into-variables-in-bash-script
IFS= read -r -d '' NS_LOG<<-EOF
*=error|warn|prefix_node|prefix_func
    :PointToPointNetDevice
    :ClockTest
       :ClockPerfect
:TcpTestSuite
:TcpRxBuffer
:TcpTxBuffer
:TcpHeader=*
:TcpL4Protocol
:TraceHelper:PointToPointHelper
EOF

echo $NS_LOG
export NS_LOG
```

but somewhere bash appends spaces between lines and instead of having the desired

```
*=error|warn|prefix_node|prefix_func:PointToPointNetDevice:ClockTest:ClockPerfect:Clock
```

I have when running $ ./launch_myscript.sh:

```
*=error|warn|prefix_node|prefix_func :PointToPointNetDevice :ClockTest :ClockPerfect :Clock etc...
```

My bash --version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I just saw in the recommended posts this one [Bash: Why is echo adding extra space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003536/bash-why-is-echo-adding-extra-space). How can I prevent NS_LOG from being considered as several arguments? Ultimately the goal is to export that variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `read` command is very explicitly treating newlines as data: By clearing IFS and passing `-d ''`, you tell `read` not to treat whitespace characters as special; since they're not special, they go into the output variable like everything else. However, you *can* take them out later:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' NS_LOG <<'EOF'
  ...content...
EOF
NS_LOG=${NS_LOG//[[:space:]]/} ## replace all whitespace with the empty string
printf '%s\n' "$NS_LOG"        ## the quotes are important!
```

See this snippet run, and its output, at http://ideone.com/fWhzBB.

---

Notes:

- `<<'EOF'` prevents expansions from occurring within the heredoc itself; with `<<EOF`, `$foo`, `$(foo)`, etc. would be special.
- `<<-` only trims leading tab characters, not any other form of whitespace; it's typically safer to do without.
- `echo $foo` string-splits and glob-expands the contents of `$foo`, passing each word created by this process as a separate argument; `echo` then places spaces between each argument. `echo "$foo"` ensures that the entire expansion is treated as a single word. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).
- Using `echo` with nontrivial or unknown data is advised against [in the relevant portion of the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html); `printf` is the preferred substitute. POSIX echo is explicitly allowed to behave in undefined ways when content contains backslash literals, and the BSD- and AT&T-derived forms of the command are explicitly incompatible, both with each other and with the common GNU implementation (providing an `-e` flag, which the POSIX spec requires to simply print `-e` on its output).

Comment: Thanks for the great comments. I've never seen the syntax (apart from vim) "${ns_log//[[:space:]]/}", is it portable ? I tried it and it works fine here thanks. Isn't there any way to make the newlines disappear just playing with the IFS & read ?

Comment: You could load content into an array using IFS and read alone, and then write that array to a string in a way that doesn't put whitespace between adjoining entries. Otherwise, not so much.

Comment: Actually -- since you're interested, I'll add a sample demonstrating. :)

Comment: Actually, I take that back. While when IFS is set to a non-empty string, this `"${foo[*]}"` expands to the elements in the array `foo` separated by the first character of its value, apparently the empty-string case is treated as equivalent to the unset case by `${foo[*]}`, despite being very different to `read`.

Comment: @mattator, ...by the way, in terms of explaining the syntax, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: @mattator, ...I also realized that I hadn't explained my use of `<<'EOF'` vs `<<EOF`; added an additional note covering that.

Comment: @mattator, ...re: portability, that particular parameter expansion is available in other ksh derivatives (in the "good ideas adopted from..." sense, not the legal sense), but is not part of the POSIX sh standard.

Answer (score 1):

things aren't that difficult. here is another solution:

```
var="`tr -d '[:space:] <<EOF'
your
  text
with
            lot of spaces
EOF`"
```

result:

```
$ echo "$var"
yourtextwithlotofspaces
```

Comment: `tr -d '[:space:]' <<'EOF'` works fine without a [useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)